# Converting zoo time series from daily to monthly means

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, lubridate

I have created a time series using zoo. It has daily values for a long period of time (40 years). I can easily plot it, but what I want is to create a time series with monthly (mean) values from this original time series and then plot it as monthly values.

I thought the package lubridate could be a good option for this and maybe there is an easy way but I don't see how. I'm a beginner in R. Has somebody a tip here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply.monthly()` from the xts package.

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix, dateFormat = "Date")
(m <- apply.monthly(x, mean))
#                Open     High      Low    Close
# 2007-01-31 50.21140 50.31528 50.12072 50.22791
# 2007-02-28 50.78427 50.88091 50.69639 50.79533
# 2007-03-31 49.53185 49.61232 49.40435 49.48246
# 2007-04-30 49.62687 49.71287 49.53189 49.62978
# 2007-05-31 48.31942 48.41694 48.18960 48.26699
# 2007-06-30 47.47717 47.57592 47.38255 47.46899
```

You might also want to convert your index from `Date` to `yearmon`, which you can do like this:

```
index(m) <- as.yearmon(index(m))
m
#              Open     High      Low    Close
# Jan 2007 50.21140 50.31528 50.12072 50.22791
# Feb 2007 50.78427 50.88091 50.69639 50.79533
# Mar 2007 49.53185 49.61232 49.40435 49.48246
# Apr 2007 49.62687 49.71287 49.53189 49.62978
# May 2007 48.31942 48.41694 48.18960 48.26699
# Jun 2007 47.47717 47.57592 47.38255 47.46899
```

Comment: thanks for your answer!, it is helpful but only one problem,  if some of my daily data are NA (even if its only one in a month) then it gives me a mean monthly value of NA. I would like it to ignore the NA's and calculate the mean with the other values. Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: and an additional question, do you know how to create accumulated monthly values instead of mean monthly values? Thanks

Comment: @OscarMolina: Add `na.rm = TRUE` to the `apply.monthly()` call to remove missing values.  What are "accumulated monthly values"?

Comment: I meant the sum, but i solved it already, thanks for your help!!

Comment: Yeah, just change `mean` to `sum`. Also, see [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate.zoo` as shown in the examples:

```
x2a <- aggregate(x, as.Date(as.yearmon(time(x))), mean)
```

if you want to stick to `zoo`.